I try to start react the app said that....npm error code ENOENT npm error syscall spawn .....what shall i do?
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin\dtplugin\deployJava1.dll
npm error path C:\Users\MKT\OneDrive\Desktop\reactJs
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin\dtplugin\deployJava1.dll ENOENT
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\MKT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-10T09_04_25_205Z-debug-0.log       
PS C:\Users\MKT\OneDrive\Desktop\reactJs>

.....i can't install the react app!!
i try to update the node and npm, check the path..!!
